# Javascript syntax inside array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have to push an array in jquery. I can't get how to properly format all javascript syntax. Can you share the best solution on this.

Result should be like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
rrApiOnReady.push(function() {
    try {
        rrApi.order({
            transaction: <transaction_id>,
            items: [
                { id: <product_id>, qnt: <quantity>,  price: <price>},
                { id: <product_id>, qnt: <quantity>,  price: <price> }
            ]
        });
    } catch(e) {}
})
</script>
```

I determine variable for 'order.cart.items' and then trying to list an array with 'items[i].product.id' like in tutorials:

```
var items = order.cart.items;
for (var i in items) { ... }
```

But it doesn't work for me to put it in the specific formatting above. It returns an error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token for.

```
rrApiOnReady.push(function() {
            try {
            rrApi.order({
            transaction: page.orderNumber,
            items: [
              for (var j in items) {
              { id: items[j].product.id, qnt: items[j].quantity,  price: items[j].product.price },
              }
                        ]
                    });
                    } catch(e) {}
                });
```

Can you please guide me how to properly format an array in such a case? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can't just put a `for` loop *inside* an array/object declaration!  You'll need to build the data structure *before* calling `rrApi.order()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use a `for` loop inside a larger structure. JavaScript's `for` loops to are not expressions which can be evaluated to a value. They are rooted in imperative programming, not functional programming.

Instead, you should use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), which *does* return a new collection based on your input collection:

```
rrApi.order({
  transaction: page.orderNumber,
  items: items.map(function (item) {
    return { id: item.product.id, qnt: item.quantity, price: item.product.price }  
  })
})
```

Comment: See [Array comprehensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Array_comprehensions), though. Was removed from ES6 draft and only included `for...of` instead of `for...in` loops. But might be reintroduced in a future version of the spec.

Comment: @Oriol Note the big **Non-standard. Do not use!**